# How to add more than one xml file per layer

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, xml, gml

I'm using this code to add xml (osm relations) files to my map.

```
osm_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML("Polygon", relation.xml, {
format: OpenLayers.Format.OSM,
style: {strokeColor: "blue"},
projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
});
```

But what I need is to add more than one relation.xml per layer, as relation1.xml, relation2.xml in the SAME layer. Until know I can only show multiple xml if they go in multiple layers.

When using vectors I just created the layer and then added the vectors by something like

```
polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                 new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon(linearRing), style);
```

And then

```
Layer.addFeatures(polygonFeature);
```

However, I can't make it work with xml / OSM relation format...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create empty vector layer and then add vector features from your files:

```
var osm = new OpenLayers.Format.OSM();
var files = ["url1", "url2", "urlN"];
var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("OSM Layer");

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    OpenLayers.Request.POST({
        url: files[i],
        success: function(e){vector.addFeatures(osm.read(e.responseText))}
    });
}
```